# Chosen TabIndex bug

Tags: jquery, tabs, shift, tabindex

I'm using jQuery chosen v 0.9.8 and some other plugins in my ASP.Net/WCF application. When I focus on the chosen, jQuery add "tabindex" attribute to chosen element with value -1. So that, with using tab key, chosen activate only once. I found a solution on the https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/commit/9085750ecd023d7a2a7c48c20ab70cc0309635b6 link. But the solution is not completely works. It fix tabindex bug, and can focus with use TAB key. But then cannot use SHIFT+TAB key when focus on chosen element. Do you have any solution or hint?

Comment: You may update your Chosen plugin as there have been more than 12 updates since 0.9.8 `http://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/`

Comment: I tried it but the latest version has shift+tab bug.

Comment: Can you post a working simplified sample (on jsfiddle for example)?

Comment: I fixed this with upgrade chosen version to v0.13.0. not latest version Nicolas. Thanks for helps...

Comment: Strange that the behaviour has been lost since this release, but good to know. FYI: releases log: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases